# WordPress REST AP - Filtering json for a custom post type based on relation to another custom post type

Tags: json, wordpress, rest

My question has to do with filtering a json request for a custom post type that has a relation to another custom post type.   I am requesting json data for an ARTIST custom post type - this works beautifully.  I can retrieve the Artists and display them on an Agent page without resubmitting the page. Works great.  I  want to filter that json request so only the ARTIST records where the ARTIST is assigned to a specific AGENT are returned.  For example:

Teddy Slatus - Agent
Steve Paul - Agent

TimeSlip -Artist managed by Steve Paul
Electric Lemurs - Artist managed by Teddy Slatus
Whoops Wrong Planet - Artist managed by Steve Paul

When the Agent detail for Steve Paul is displayed, Click a button labeled "manages" and display a list of Steve Paul's Artists right below Steve Paul's detail.  I have most of this work complete and it works BUT I can't figure out how to filter my Artist json request so that only Steve Paul's Artists are returned in the json.  I do have the relationship custom field set up for Artist --> Agent and Agent --> Artist.  I am not seeing anything in the Artist json that I can use to filter by Agent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take my best guess at this without knowing exactly what your json looks like. If you're doing a request for a custom post type "Artist", and the artist's agent is saved in a custom field then I think you can get it with:

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'artist'
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'agent',
            'value' => $agent_name,
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And then looping through $query with `while ( $the_query->have_posts() )`

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to filter from two different post type than you need to fire two different wp_query and than you can  Get the two post types along with their acf meta and use [PHP Array Functions ( like Array Interset)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to get the common/union or intersection.

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy little plugin that has a great track record and is still maintained.  Install it, activate it and BAM! all of the custom fields are exposed on the REST API!  If you are a WordPress developer simply search plugins for:

ACF to REST API

Thanks to all who contributed ideas to this thread.

Mark